# tryCatch: Why is warning handled as error?

Tags: r, try-catch

Why is the following code not returning `2` but handles the warning as an error?

```
tryCatch({
  1+1
  warning("test")
  return(2)
}, error=function(e){
  print("error")
}, finally = {})

[1] "error"
Warning message:
In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : test
```

How can I only handle errors but ignore warnings?

Comment: Don't use `return`. Just `2` will suffice.

Comment: @jbaums After realizing my foolishness I realize that your suggestion completely fixes the problem since the error was coming from them using return outside of a function.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While you are manually triggering a `warning`, your expression also throws an error because you are using `return` outside of a function.

This becomes more obvious if you return the error message itself within `function(e)` (rather than printing "error"):

```
tryCatch({
  1+1
  warning("test")
  return(2)
}, error=function(e) {
  e
})

# <simpleError in doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler): 
#  no function to return from, jumping to top level>
# Warning message:
# In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : test
```

(Note this is equivalent to excluding the `error` argument.)

This is the same error message you'll see if you enter `return(2)` at the R console:

```
return(2)
# Error: no function to return from, jumping to top level
```

To remedy the problem, remove the `return` call from within your expression, like this:

```
tryCatch({
  1+1
  warning("test")
  2
}, error=function(e){
  print('error')
})

# [1] 2
# Warning message:
# In doTryCatch(return(expr), name, parentenv, handler) : test
```